# Create Temp Table based on Restore Filelistonly Results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, restore

I am trying to create a temp table that contains the LogicalName, PhysicalName, Type and FileGroupName. I need this script to be SQL version Agnostic.

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = 'C:\BackupFile'
```

I can do this by creating the table first and then insert the information however as the results set of `RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK` changes per version i would need one script per SQL version.

Im not sure if this is possible but any assistance would be very helpful

Comment: As you stated you know the results change per version. As such you can't have one code to rule them all. You will need a different definition for different versions.

Comment: That was my fear i was hoping there was some black magic way this could be done with out having a script per version.

Comment: @SeanLange You could write code to handle all version at least to some extent.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda that is sort of true. But the OP is looking for a write once and forget it solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `INSERT INTO EXEC`:

```
CREATE TABLE temp(...);    

INSERT INTO temp(LogicalName, PhysicalName, Type, FileGroupName,...)
EXEC('RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = ''C:\BackupFile''');

SELECT * FROM temp;
```

**EDIT:**

To be version independent [getting version](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1140/how-to-tell-what-sql-server-version-you-are-running/):

```
DECLARE @version NVARCHAR(100) = 
 CASE 
     WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY ('productversion')) like '8%' THEN 'SQL2000'
     WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY ('productversion')) like '9%' THEN 'SQL2005'
     WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY ('productversion')) like '10.0%' THEN 'SQL2008'
     WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY ('productversion')) like '10.5%' THEN 'SQL2008 R2'
     WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY ('productversion')) like '11%' THEN 'SQL2012'
     WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY ('productversion')) like '12%' THEN 'SQL2014'
     WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY ('productversion')) like '13%' THEN 'SQL2016'     
     WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY ('productversion')) like '14%' THEN 'SQL2017' 
     ELSE 'unknown'
  END;

-- pseudocode
IF @version = 'SQL2017'
  EXEC('CREATE TABLE temp(col1, col2, col3)');

IF @version = 'SQL2016'
  EXEC('CREATE TABLE temp(col1, col2, col3, col4)');

IF @version = 'SQL2014'
  EXEC('CREATE TABLE temp(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)');

-- no column list(blind insert)
EXEC('INSERT INTO temp   
      EXEC(''RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = ''''C:\BackupFile'''' '')');
GO

-- common columns only
SELECT LogicalName, PhysicalName, Type, FileGroupName
FROM temp;
```

Comment: The issue with this is you have to specify the Temp table columns and the Column list is different per SQL version and i need this script to be Agnostic of SQL version if possible.